# Passing flashvars to Flex

Tags: html, flash, flash-builder, flashvars

As a PHP junior encountering Flex for the first time this scratches my brain for days. The flashvar contains the source of the video I wnat to play in the Flex video component. The HTML of the player looks like:

```
 function createPlayer(videoSource){
    document.writeln("<div id=\"player\">");
    document.writeln("<object width=\"489\" height=\"414\" FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\">");
    document.writeln("<param name=\"player\" value=\"bin-debug/FlexPlayer.swf\">");
    document.writeln("<embed src=\"bin-debug/FlexPlayer.swf\" name=\"player\" width=\"489\" height=\"414\" FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\">");
    document.writeln("</embed>");
    document.writeln("</object>");
    document.writeln("</div>");               
}
```

I tried to call the FlashVars in the FlexPlayer.mxml but it's not working. Please tell me what I have to apply in the source in the mxml to access the FlashVars.

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="Player" left="0" top="0" width="497" height="414"
                       skinClass="MySkin" source="FlashVars"/>
    </s:Group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the variable `videoSource` contain? If it is an URL to a video and nothing more, it probably won't work, since flashvars is supposed to be a string that contains variable names and values (not just values).

So for example, `flashvars="video.flv"` won't work, but `flashvars="sourceUrl=video.flv"` can work, if the video player is made to use a variable named `sourceUrl`.

Also, for the `object` element you should add a separate `param` element for the flashvars, instead of having flashvars as an attribute of the `object` element. For the `embed` element, flashvars is an attribute, as you have it now (aint standards great ;)

More info:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html

Comment: How exactly should the code look for the param element (<param name="FlashVars"/>)

Answer (score 1):

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void {
            // The FlashVars
            var obj:Object = Application.application.parameters;
            var videoSource:String = (obj.videoSource != null) ? obj.videoSource : "there was no flashVar by this name";
            trace(videoSource);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: and everything other is right? I should only add this function in order to have the player working properly?

Comment: no. adding this function will put the flashVar into a variable. you will have to figure out the rest.